# Multiply/add Stackdriver metric in grafana

Tags: grafana, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to multiply/add the stackdriver metric by a factor(say MetricA*10)?
FYI - I’m using Grafana v7.0

Comment: Stackdriver just delivers the information to you, you are going to have to transform it once exported and then re-export it again to Grafana. You can also have a look to this [link](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/stackdriver/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Alexandre, Is it possible to apply some mathematical operation on metrics while pulling stackdriver metrics to grafana?

Comment: no, you are going to need to modify it in between somewhere, not sure how you'd accomplish this. But Stackdriver is the wrong path to follow. You are going to need an intermediary to do modify the metric and then export them to grafana.

Comment: Currently, I'm pulling metrics to a server and after modification, pushing it back to Grafana using Influxdb. It's working fine.
I just wanted to remove some overheads. Anyways, Thanks @Alexandre